# How to check if power cable is connected from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, battery

I'm running ubuntu on my notebook and I need a way to check (from the command line) if the power cable is connected. Is there any system file that keeps log of this? or is there a bash command that will help me?

I need this for a script that will behave differently depending on whether the power cord is plugged in or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/ACAD/state
state:                   on-line
```

or somthing similar depending on your architecture. There are many exports of machine state hiding in the /proc psuedo-directory.

Comment: Works exactly like that. Only it was /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state in my case.

Answer (score 20):

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online 
1
 [pull power]
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online 
0
```

The value to put in place of `ADP1` may vary.

Comment: Works exactly like that as well, only with "/sys/class/power_supply/AC/online" for me. I marked the other answer as accepted 'cause it was first, but both worked equally well.

Comment: I only have a BAT0 directory in `/sys/class/power_supply`. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks! The Ubuntu22 has a bug which cause the right-upper power suply icon can't work correctly, So I need this command to check whether my power spply cable works. And in my Ubuntu22 laptop environment my power supply status file is at here: "/sys/class/power_supply/AC0/online", it's 1 when cable plugged in, and 0 when plugged off.

Answer (score 6):

Use the command **[`on_ac_power`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/on_ac_power.1.html)**.

```
on_ac_power && echo on ac || echo on batt
```

Comment: This is indeed the simplest solution and the command seems to be preinstalled at least on Debian/Ubuntu machines in package [powermgmt-base](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/all/powermgmt-base/filelist). See also [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/on_ac_power.1.html).

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 5):

I use something similar  to:

```
acpi -a | grep AC | cut -d: -f2
```

in order to display the battery status on the wmii status bar.

Comment: This one didn't work with me because the acpi command wasn't installed. I didn't install it because the other methods were more practical, but it probably works fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/386949/how-to-check-if-the-ac-laptop-adapter-is-plugged-or-not, simply run:

```
acpi -a
```

which can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

The output will tell you `Adapter 0: on-line` if plugged, or `Adapter 0: off-line` if un-plugged.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Answer (score 2):

For me `ADP1/online` was not available so I had to cat another file in the same `power_supply` dir i.e.

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online
```

Connected : `1`

Not connected : `0`

Comment: It is `ACAD` for me: `cat /sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/online`.